# No more than two words inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a normal input field. I want to make sure that **no more than two words can be entered inside the input field**. I am not concerned with the no of chracter. I am concerned with the number of words. Can this be done with jQuery Validation? If not, how about with jQuery/javascript?

```
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 control-label" for="firstName">Quote created by : *</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="firstName" name="firstName" value=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a validation method.

Ading the method

```
$.validator.addMethod("wordCount",
   function(value, element, params) {
      var typedWords = value.match(/\b/g).length / 2;

      if(typedWords <= params[0]) {
         return true;
      }
   },
   jQuery.format("Only {0} words allowed.")
);
```

Validating

```
$("#contactform").validate({
   rules: {
      firstName: {
         required: true,
         wordCount: ['2']
      }
   },
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/DXUX7/)

Based on code from [element design](http://elementdesignllc.com/2011/06/jquery-validation-word-count-custom-method/).

Found on Google by searching `jquery validate maximum words`.

Comment: The example is for textfield. I need for normal input field please